# Asynchronous method in JavaEE 6

Tags: asynchronous, java-ee-6

I trying to use **Asynchronous** method in JavaEE 6. I created Following classes. However, the result of output log is **synchronous**. It's not correct.

Stateless Class

```
   @javax.ejb.Stateless
    public class MailManager implements Serializable{
    @Asynchronous
        public void send(List<String> toList, Mail mail, final SystemSetting systemSetting) throws MailException, UnsupportedEncodingException{

            boolean isError = false;
            for(InternetAddress addr :addressList){
                    MimeMessage msg = getMimeMessage(addr, mail, session);
                    Transport.send(msg);
                    log.info("Sent email to ["+addr+"].");
            }
            if(isError){
                throw new MailException("Mail sending error occurred. Check error log.");
            }
            log.debug("Async finish.");
        }
    }
```

ManagedBean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MailController extends AbstractController{
    @Inject @new(MailCreater.class)
    private MailFactory mailCreater;

    @Inject
    private MailManager mailManager;

    public void send(){
        Mail mail = null;
            mail = mailCreater.createFromTemplate(this, false,
                    mimeInfo, "template/testTemplate.txt","template/FOOTER1.body", map);
            mailManager.send(list, mail, systemSetting);
        log.debug("send() finish.");
    }
}
```

log

```
INFO[Log4jLogger] - Sent email to [test1@test.co.jp].
INFO [Log4jLogger] - Sent email to [test2@test.co.jp].
.
.
.
DEBUG [Log4jLogger] - Async finish.
DEBUG [Log4jLogger] - send() finish.
```

#### Update

Error Code when I change @Inject to @EJB

```
warning : javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException:
javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:454)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2547)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1899)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EjbAsyncTask.call(EjbAsyncTask.java:99)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not
create stateless EJB
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:726)
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:247)
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:449)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:988)
        at
org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:1076)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:148)
        at
org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:169)
        at
org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:146)
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1639)
        at
com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code MailController.send() sample is missing how you are currently getting the reference to MailManager. I assume mailManager is the reference but the sample doesn't show how that reference is made so I am flying a little blind here in terms of telling you exactly what's wrong.

However, in general, what you need to do is inject the MailManager EJB into MailController with something like `@EJB MailManager mailManager;`

Also its looks like you are relying on your logs to tell you if things are really going async or not. This can be problematic due to timing. Also the log snippet you have included does not include the "Sent email to" message which it looks like `MailManager.send()` should be emitting if all goes well.

**-- Update --**

@KensukeSato raised a good question which was, "Should I use `@Inject` or `@EJB` as both 'work' in his case?"

It basically comes down to the fact the as of JavaEE6 CDI beans and EJB beans provide different functionality and that EJB session beans ARE CDI beans but CDI beans are not EJB session beans. So if you simply want EJB services you can use `@EJB` to inject your session bean into your CDI bean. However, if in addition to `@EJB` services you want the bean to leverage CDI services then you should use `@Inject`.

What does CDI give you that EJB alone does not?

- Annotation-based programming model; stereotypes
- Type-safe injection, interceptors, decorators
- Context management, scopes, conversations
- Events and observers
- Producers and disposers
- Extensibility via custom scopes; programmatically defined beans; etc.

So if you need any of that in addition to EJB functionality then you would use `@Inject`, otherwise you can simply use `@EJB`.

Comment: I corrected my Sample Code. I inject MailManager by @Inject. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks for the update, did you try changing `@Inject` to `@EJB`?

Comment: I changed ＠Inject to ＠EJB, but I had the Exception. I add the Error code. And I had clues to the problem. First I placed MailManager to Lib Project, and MailController to Web Project. It's not work when ＠Inject and ＠EJB. Second, I placed MailManager, MailCOntroller in same project w.  It's work when ＠Inject!

Comment: @KensukeSato I would be curious to know if it also works with `@EJB` with your new packaging layout. I prefer injecting EJBs that way because I know its the EJB container performing the injection vs the CDI container.

Comment: When I use ＠EJB My Project worked fine, too.  I placed MailManager, MailCOntroller in same project.　Which the annotaion I should use, ＠EJB or ＠Inject?

Comment: @KensukeSato since its an EJB I prefer to use `@EJB`. You might find this link useful http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ejb-3-1-175064.html

Comment: ＠NBW Thanks for tell me about your userful info. I'm going to use ＠EJB! I close my question.

Comment: Great, glad you found it helpful. I also added some addition details around your followup question.